# Will This Curl Script Breach the Intended Website's Robot.txt File

Tags: php, curl

I'm setting up a PHP script to screen scrape a website 2-5 times a day through a server using Curl. All it does is retrieve the website's html. However the website I am intending to target has the robot.txt saying "User-agent: * Disallow: /". Will this script breach their robot.txt, and consider my script a robot.

I know the slash afterwards a disallow means no crawlers allowed, but is my script considered a crawler. Or is function like get_file_content() and Curling under the same definition as web crawling and bots.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

sleep(300);

$html = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$html = tidy_repair_string($html);

$doc = new \DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$x_path = new \DOMXpath($doc);

$nodes = $x_path->query('//div[@class="id"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    echo $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes.. `User-agent: * Disallow: /` = `All user-agents disallow: /`, which is everything.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your php script is considered a robot, and

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

means "no robots allowed", which unfortunately includes your script.